# Java class SingularMatrixException not found

Tags: java, apache, noclassdeffounderror

I get a NoClassDefFoundError exception for org/apache/commons/math/linear/SingularMatrixException.

Does anybody know what JAR file I need in order to resolver this?

I tried adding 'commons-math3-3.2.jar' to my project's Java Build Path, but that didn't help.

Or is there something else that I am missing in my project settings?

Thanks

Comment: Try http://mavenhub.com/mvn/central/org.apache.commons/commons-math/2.0, the class is listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

org/apache/commons/math/linear/SingularMatrixException is [commons-math](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.commons|commons-math|2.2|jar), not commons-math3.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking on [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org) - the advanced search let's you enter a class name:

[http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22org.apache.commons.math.linear.SingularMatrixException%22](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3a%22org.apache.commons.math.linear.SingularMatrixException%22)

To extend Markus Malkusch answer - the last org.apache.commons/commons-math version it's in is 2.2